# Export only a part of web page to PDF using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, export-to-pdf

Is it possible to export only a part of webpage to PDF using PhantomJS? I tried setting `page.clipRect` options for a small portion of the page before rendering to PDF but still the exported PDF shows the entire webpage.